# Django Generador de Contraseñas

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hola recientemente tengo que generar un password aleatorio y unico para cada usuario que tengo en el Model.User.

He probado con Python a generar números y letras con las librerias `random` y `string`.

```
import random, string
pass = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(10)
```

Pero creo que esto no es nada eficiente.

Django provee alguna solución ?

Comment: Creo que tendrías que buscar en la documentación del proyecto. Si el código que publicas funciona, aunque sea de forma ineficiente, no hay problema que resolver. Si intentas algo y tienes problema en tu implementación, entonces pregunta todo lo que necesites e incluye un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender tu problema.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es una solicitud de búsqueda.

Comment: En estos casos que tendría que hacer, no se puede debatir sobre una solución ineficiente? Debería de borrar la pregunta ? Gracias.

Comment: Pues es por el formato y el alcance definido para el sitio, preguntas tipo "mejora mi código" se consideran basadas en opiniones y eso es causal de cierre. Busca un generador de password __con Python__ e impleméntalo en Django. Hay unos muy buenos basado en el comic XKCD. Y si, tal vez sea mejor borrar esta pregunta.

Comment: No es intentar mejorar mi código, es debatir sobre si hay una solución mas eficiente a ese problema, lo voy a plantear en stackoverflow meta, la solución la he encontrado en la documentación de Django, muchas gracias por tu aporte, he visto que soluciona muy bien el problema.

Comment: Yoel que yo sepa en Django se puede usar `django.utils.crypto.get_random_string` y `django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password` (es posible que esto es lo que has encontrado en la documentación). Por otro lado `random` no es seguro al ser pseudoaleatorio. En Python puro se podria usar `random.SystemRandom()`, `os.urandom()` o `secrets` (Python >= 3.6). En el código que muestras se pueden hacer mejoras pero el impacto real es mínimo, al fin y al cabo generas cadenas de 10 caracteres y además, creo que debe siempre primar la seguridad en estos casos a la eficiencia.

Comment: @toledano yo creo que esta pregunta es válida puesto que está exponiendo el tema. Investigar por horas leyendo la documentación vs publicar una pregunta de alguien que sepa al respecto y pueda, no sé, ¿ayudarte y ayudar a otras personas con lo mismo? ¿Quizás eso lo ves como algo fuera del alcance del sitio?

Comment: Recomiendo no borrar la pregunta. Puede que se cierre pero eso no significa que debas borrarla.

Comment: @FJSevilla eso puede constituir una respuesta a esta pregunta.

Comment: @FJSevilla he probado [make_random_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py) y me parece una solución poco segura al problema.

Sin embargo [get_random_string](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py), me la hashea con sha-256 antes de devolvermela, esto si lo veo eficiente y seguro.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración @LuiggiMendozaJ no encontraba ninguna guía en la documentación al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django provee soluciones al problema, investigando y probando, creo que la mas segura y eficiente es [Get Randon String](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py) porque el string es encriptado con un algoritmo sha-256 antes de devolverlo, aquí va un ejemplo con un poco de código.

Podemos pasarle como argumento la longitud que deseamos de contraseña.

```
>>> from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
>>> password = get_random_string(length=32)
>>> password
u'rRVXe32N27g3aHoAS218KdVaqPSD12fp'
```

Y también podemos pasarle como argumento los caracteres que permitimos para que haga una combinación de ellos.

```
>>> from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
>>> password = get_random_string(length=32,allowed_chars='ABCD')
>>> password
u'CCCAAAABDACDBCCAACAABCDDCCAABBAD'
```

La otra solución que provee Django es [Make Random Password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password) que permite hacer lo mismo pero lo que pasa es que no la encripta. Importar el BaseUserManager y también acepta los parametros `length` y `allowed_chars` para la longitud y los caracteres permitidos.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
>>> password = BaseUserManager().make_random_password(45)
>>> password
u'jypVaXuw9Uw8mD4CXtEhtj2E4DVYx23YTMwy8jGTKsreR'
```

Si necesitamos algo mas fuerte Django provee [Make Password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py), que nos convierte texto plano en una password generada por el algoritmo hash directamente.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
>>> password = make_password('')
>>> password
u'pbkdf2_sha256$30000$JuKXdW3shCjL$PsPJX7Zale5JUBkWpIJI/+QlsuVWhz9Q+GQWVtTpQ/Y='
```